# How to enable SageMaker Projects and Jumpstart on a SageMaker domain using CLI or terraform?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I can edit the SageMaker Domain via the AWS Console > Sagemaker > Domains > xxxx > Domain settings > Edit > Studio settings > SageMaker Projects and JumpStart

[image]

But how can I achieve the same thing by using AWS CLI commands and / or terraform ?

Is there a list of exactly all that the console does when I enable all those options? I'm assuming that it will create at least the IAM Roles described at [AWS Managed Policies for SageMaker projects and JumpStart](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/security-iam-awsmanpol-sc.html), and probably other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console action performs the below-

1. Creates all the required roles for JumpStart and projects
2. Enables ServiceCatalog portfolio for the domain
3. Associates your domain's roles with the portfolio.

To automate this, create the required roles in your account (you've already linked the managed policies above). Instructions for steps 2 and 3 are in the blog here - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/machine-learning/enable-amazon-sagemaker-jumpstart-for-custom-iam-execution-roles/

Link to CLI commands:

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sagemaker/enable-sagemaker-servicecatalog-portfolio.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/servicecatalog/associate-principal-with-portfolio.html